# Trying to move a file between folders in LeoCad

Tags: filesystem, shared-folders, copy-and-paste

*First of all: Hi, I'm an Ubuntu newbie (recently switched to 18.04 Bionic Beaver two months ago) so not a expert, very inept with terminal sudo commands.*

I have a problem with [LeoCad][1] and folders. It supports installing additional files for more bricks, which need to go into a folder.  The intention is to move a zip file from the **Downloads** folder into a library folder named **usr/share/leocad/library.bin**

But neither <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> or right-click-then-paste work. What is the intended terminal command code for moving the file?

@ K7AAY: File manager only shows it as a zip file, no options to move the file. The bin folder in the share directory shows paste as greyed out text (disabled)

Offical guide says 
https://www.leocad.org/docs/library.html

> Linux: The path is “../share/leocad/library.bin”, which is relative to
>   the application binary folder. If you have the LeoCAD executable
>   “/usr/bin/leocad”, the application will look for the library in
>   “/usr/share/leocad/library.bin”.

Comment: What happens when you use the Files manager app to copy the file into /usr/share/leocad/library.bin/ ? Do the bricks appear in LeoCad? Please click [edit] and report the result.

Answer (score 0):

Supposed your file is named `bricks.zip` and it is located in your Downloads folder, you'd have to issue a command like:

```
mv ~/Downloads/bricks.zip /usr/share/leocad/
```

where `mv` stands for move and `~` is a shortcut to your home directory.

Comment: @Jugmacoo: are you sure it's either that or add library.bin at the end? or try both? or like this 
mv ~/Downloads/bricks.zip /usr/share/leocad/library.bin
.

since it needs that folder in the instructions, i'm gonna try this weekend.

Comment: I think the documentation is a little bit ambiguous. You could also create an issue at their Github project and get help there, as it is less a technical problem, but more an informational one. https://github.com/leozide/leocad/issues

Comment: No good added 2 separate files for luck, one in the first and the other in the library.bin folder and no results 

after opening program it opens, says default cannot find any compatible parts and still only loads up the default parts.
The big lack of angled parts is a bummer. 
Earlier this month i tried installing the windows based Lego Digital Designer 4.3.3 (which in theory works with Wine and Games On Linux installer... has been a absolute failure)

Comment: re-installation is broken now unmet dependecies issue. follow here for details.https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2431453&p=13907564#post13907564